# How can you customise CRM for Outlook so that Convert to Lead asks for all required fields?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We made a new field in the Lead entity in CRM and made it required.

We're trying out the CRM for Outlook add-in and when we convert to a Lead, it asks for Surname, Company Name, email etc. but not our required field. This means that when you hit Save as Lead, it fails as the entity is looking for our custom required field to be there.

Is it possible to change the form that Outlook shows? I would have hoped any customisations would have surfaced automatically through this form since CRM allows you to customise the entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out that Outlook actually does bypass any custom fields which you've made required. It was the plugin I had which was throwing the error as I was expecting it to be populated, whereas Outlook leaves it alone. A quick check works fine